# Request header for uploading the image using twitpic in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, twitter, java-me, oauth, twitpic

I want to upload an image to the user's twitter account. For this, I need a URL which I will get in from of a json response.

I know the URL where the request should be sent i.e. 'http://api.twitpic.com/2/upload.json', but what should be the parameters for the request that I don't know.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

which language you are using?

For now, check the examples here http://twittown.com/forums/showthread.php?t=768 and [using TwitPic + OAuth to upload a photo + tweet to Twitter (.NET C#) - why no tweet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434576/using-twitpic-oauth-to-upload-a-photo-tweet-to-twitter-net-c-why-no-tw)

They detailed every thing how to Twitpic including the OAuth

Comment: Hi Shiva, thanks for reply.The language which I am using is java and the api is of rim(blackberry).The link which you mention is for .Net.Do you have any information about it related to blackberry?

Comment: this link from stockobverflow explains that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247956/twitpic-oauth-echo-java-j2ee