# Unity3d Upload a Image to Twitter

Tags: c#, twitter, unity-game-engine

I am able to login and tweet text message but not able to share an image on twitter.

When I upload the image it gives the response, but when I did not post image on twitter, I got the following response.

**This is my code** :-

```
    private const string UploadMediaURL = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json";

    public static IEnumerator UploadMedia(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, AccessTokenResponse response)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        Texture2D tex= Resources.Load("imag") as Texture2D;
        byte[] dataToSave = tex.EncodeToPNG ();
        string encoded64ImageData = System.Convert.ToBase64String( dataToSave );
        parameters.Add("media_data",encoded64ImageData);
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm(); // Add data to the form to post.
        form.AddField("media_data", encoded64ImageData );
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string auth = GetHeaderWithAccessToken("POST", UploadMediaURL, consumerKey, consumerSecret, response, parameters);
        Debug.Log ("Auth   " + auth);
        headers.Add( "Authorization", auth);
        headers.Add( "Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64");
        WWW web = new WWW(UploadMediaURL,form.data, headers);
        yield return web;
        Debug.Log ("Response  " + web.text);
    }
```

**Response** :-

```
{
"media_id":700577726298599424,
"media_id_string":"700577726298599424",
"size":9734,
"expires_after_secs":86400,
"image":
        {
         "image_type":"image\/png",
         "w":435,
         "h":159
         }
}
```

This is my Posting Source Code With Media_Id. When I use it without media_id it posts successfully. But when I give a media_id parameter with it, it gives me  an error

failed. 401 Unauthorized{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

**Source Code**:-

```
    private const string PostTweetURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

    public static IEnumerator PostTweet(string text, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, AccessTokenResponse response, PostTweetCallback callback)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text.Length > 140)
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("PostTweet - text[{0}] is empty or too long.", text));

            callback(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("status", text);

            WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
            form.AddField("status", text);
            form.AddField ("media_id", "732498072731713536");
            // HTTP header
            var headers = new Dictionary<string,string>();

            headers["Authorization"] = GetHeaderWithAccessToken("POST", PostTweetURL, consumerKey, consumerSecret, response, parameters);

            WWW web = new WWW(PostTweetURL, form.data, headers);
            yield return web;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(web.error))
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("PostTweet - failed. {0}\n{1}", web.error, web.text));
                callback(false);
            }
            else
            {
                string error = Regex.Match(web.text, @"<error>([^&]+)</error>").Groups[1].Value;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    Debug.Log(string.Format("PostTweet - failed. {0}", error));
                    callback(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    callback(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And where is the code you use to do so?

Comment: I have edit in my code. Please refer to it and give a possible solution.Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

It makes perfect sense that this does not appear on twitter. The code you are currently provided is only meant to upload a image to the twitter service, which then can be attached in twitter status updates.

> For example, a media_id value can be used to create a Tweet with an attached photo using the statuses/update endpoint. [source](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload)

So after uploading your image, and receiving the `media_id` which can be used in the [update](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update)

> Updates the authenticating user’s current status, also known as Tweeting.

**Edit**

> This is my Posting Source Code With Media_Id. When I use it without media_id it posts successfully. But when I give a media_id parameter with it, it gives me an error
>
> failed. 401 Unauthorized{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

You are receiving this error because you are not being verified. As the error itself states as well. As mentioned in the [update](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) docs there are some things you have to keep in mind when [uploading media](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media). As mentioned here, POST and query parameters are not used when calculation an OAuth signature, unlike a general tweet.

> Because the method uses **multipart POST**, OAuth is handled a little differently. POST or query string parameters are not used when calculating an OAuth signature basestring or signature. Only the oauth_* parameters are used.

[Why no tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4434576/2030635) has some pretty good answers in regards to this authentication.

Comment: I need some more information for it . Can you provide me source code for that as  i am not able to complete it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Flexsin_Unity What exactly are you having issues with? You mentioned that you can already successfully post text. Adding a image is only a slight addition to this.

Comment: What is that slight addition in that i need to know . I have struggle a lot in that thing. But i do not get it done. Please help me in posting image file to twitter.

Comment: @Flexsin_Unity Refer to [update](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update). You will need to include the `media_id` as a parameter in your `tweet`. If you require more assistance on this I would request you to include the code you currently use for tweeting text inside your question as well

Comment: :- I have add my positing code with media id on my first question Source Code . can You Please Refer it . It gives me error line :-                   failed. 401 Unauthorized
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}  when i give media_id . Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Now How can i change my code so that i do not get authentication error.

Comment: Can you Please help me what things i have to change to upload any media file  in my code.                                                                                                    Thanks in Advance.